# Excel Automation: read a csv file and update an Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I have an automated test which produces a csv with two columns of data.
I have an excel file which I use to gather the results of all the runs in a worksheet.

I want to fully automate the process of updating the Excel file after each test run.

This is probably what I want to do:

```
1. Read the two columns from the CSV file
2. Paste the two columns in a worksheet in the excel file, in the first 
   empty column to the right of the existing block of columns.
3. Save the Excel file
```

EDIT:

Now i understand that i can do steps 1-3 using a macro.
All that is left for me to figure out is how to launch the macro.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate Excel Spreadsheet from CSV (ASP.NET C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184573/generate-excel-spreadsheet-from-csv-asp-net-c)

Comment: How is my question a duplicate of your suggested link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the csv and write to the Excel sheet with a single data provider, the OleDb provider. Here is an [article](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/05/26/2973.aspx) on how to write to Excel, and [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/246786-read-csv-file-oledb) is one on how to read csv.

Answer (score 0):

Once you write the macro, it should be in the macro list in Excel for that Excel document. You can bind the macro to a keystroke (like Alt-i, Alt-whatever) so that it runs when your press that key combination.

I've done this on a couple of similar projects where I need to import CSV files from other sources and put the data into an Excel sheet (or sheets)

Comment: But i still want the macro to be invoked automatically, without me having to do the keystroke.